# How can we migrate inventory of files and components from one teamsite server to another? (unix box)

Tags: components, migrate, dct, teamsite

I have certain list of files (and components).
We basically have two environments - test and prod.
The new site has been set up in test and needs to migrate to prod.

Any way to do this? Also does this migration not impact UIDs (unique Ids/internal IDs)?

Comment: Most of the times since they are large number of files we move files via windows explorer related tools. I use Beyond Compare Sync to track changes and merge. That is faster and better.

Comment: OpenDeploy could be used for this, if you have it

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what version and environment you are using, you have a few options. One option for any 6.7.X or lower is to use a content migration workflow(possibly would need development) which would migrate content from one server to another. Another option is to run an rysnc from the command line (syntax below):

```
rsync -rpog -e ssh user@servername:/path/syncing/from.* /path/syncing/to
```

Similarly there is a secure copy command(shown below). However, while secure copy preserves dates, rsync works a little faster.

```
scp -p user@servername:/path/copying/from.* /path/copying/to
```

Your last option for a 7.X environment is to build and run a spar, shown in the white papers, which would migrate the content as well.